# ACM CCS concepts

Tags: paper-submission, acm

I want to generate the ACM Computing Classification System (CCS) concepts code in latex. My topic comes under the title Biometrics. But I could not find the broad category where in I could place Biometrics. So, how do I select the category for ACM CCS concepts?

Comment: I disagree with the close votes: coping with ACM CCS is a frequent frustration faced by a large fraction of the computer science community.

Comment: Perhaps this question can be edited to be a bit more general.

Answer (score 8):

Navigating the ACM CCS tree from the top can be really frustrating, often leaving you lost in a twisty maze of categories apparently all alike.  However, the ACM also provides access to the whole classification system directly [as a single flat webpage](http://dl.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=2371137&ftid=1290923&dwn=1).  You can then search for words related to what you're looking for in that single page, often finding them at some low level of the tree.

In your particular case, for example, "biometrics" appears in two locations:

- Security and privacy -> Security services -> Authentication -> Biometrics
- Computing methodologies -> Artificial intelligence -> Computer vision -> Computer vision tasks -> Biometrics

Personally, however, I recommend not stressing over classification much. So far as I can tell, this system is largely obsolete, given modern search technology, and I have never personally used, nor heard of anyone else using, these categories for anything other than fulfilling requirements from the ACM.

Comment: ... not to mention the confusion between version 1998 and 2012 of CCS...